# Find all the numbers $\overline{abcd}$ (4-digit number in base 10) that check the relationship. $5a^2+5b^2+2c^2+2d^2-2ac-2cd-4ab-4bd-16a+16b-4d+20=0$

Tags: square-numbers

**the question**

Find all the numbers $\overline{abcd}$ (4-digit number in base 10) that check the relationship. $$5a^2+5b^2+2c^2+2d^2-2ac-2cd-4ab-4bd-16a+16b-4d+20=0$$

**my idea**

I tried grouping them in a whole perfect square or I tried using formulas such as

$$a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$$

$$a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$$

I tried many of this variants but none of them got me to a useful form.

I don't know where to start! THope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: what is d? please elaborate as you gave the number as $\overline{abc}$, so should the number be $\overline{abcd}$?

Comment: @peterwhy see the edited. sorry for my misspelling.

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya see the edited. sorry for my misspelling

Comment: I do not see any useful sort of pattern and would resort to coding a brute force search.  In doing so, you can find the only solution is $2022$.

Comment: I think you meant $\overline{abcd}$ where you typed $\overline{abc}$ in the question, and *satisfy the relationship* in the places where you typed *check the relationship*

Comment: Is $a=0$ allowed?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given expression can be written
$$    (a-c)^2 +(c-d)^2  + (2a-b-4)^2  + (2b-d+2)^2$$
Knowing this is zero, immediately gives us
$$\overline{abcd}=2022$$
I confess that it took me a while to find this - annoyingly WA was no help.

Comment: You should preferably use $\overline{abcd} \ $  in place of $abcd$.

Comment: @Sahaj - I have done so. Although I am not familiar with that notation.

Comment: nice idea...I wrote   software   for what Kap called a "homothety"  meaning  take symmetric integer matrices $A,B,$   find out if there are any matrices $P$  of integers with $P^T A P = B$  where   I also supply a bound on the absolute values of the entries of $P.$  Taking just the quadratic form part only, it returns exactly your expression (without the constants $-4,2$ ).  If I'd thought to check that....

Answer (score 1):

Complete square with respect to $a$, then $b$, then $c$, then $d$.
The left side turns out to be
$$ 5 \left(a -\frac{2 b}{5}-\frac{c}{5}-\frac{8}{5}\right)^{2} + 
\frac{21}{5} \left(b -\frac{2 c}{21}+\frac{8}{7}-\frac{10 d}{21}\right)^{2}
+ \frac{37}{21} \left(c -\frac{24}{37}-\frac{25 d}{37}\right)^{2}+ 
\frac{9}{37} \left(d -2\right)^{2}$$
and the unique solution to the equations
$$ \eqalign{a -\frac{2 b}{5}-\frac{c}{5}-\frac{8}{5} &= 0\cr
b -\frac{2 c}{21}+\frac{8}{7}-\frac{10 d}{21} &= 0\cr
c -\frac{24}{37}-\frac{25 d}{37} &= 0\cr
d - 2 &= 0\cr}$$
is $a = 2$, $b = 0$, $c = 2$, $d = 2$.

Comment: Completing the square always comes in so handy. +1.